# Align tikz bullet in beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to create a custom bullet for `beamer` using TikZ but for some reason it comes out improperly aligned (in particularly the bullet is slightly higher then the center of the text). How do I fix this?

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}{\tikz\node[] {\tikz\draw[black,fill=gray] (0,0) circle (0.1);};}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame} 
\frametitle{test}
\begin{itemize} 
\item Align this properly
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This outputs,
[image]

(Notice the vertical position of the bullet compared to the text)

Answer (score 3):

You can adjust the `baseline`. I have also modified the code for drawing the bullet.

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}{\tikz[baseline={(a.south)}]\node[draw,circle,black,fill=gray,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=2mm] (a){};}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{test}
\begin{itemize}
\item Align this properly
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome thanks! Is there a reason to use \node instead of \draw? I like the infinite freedom of \draw.

Comment: @JeffDror: A node has anchor which can be used to align while draw doesn't. :)

Answer (score 3):

Simply don't nest `tikzpicture`s (as a general rule this should always be avoided) and you can keep all the `\draw` freedom:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}{\tikz\draw[black,fill=gray] (0,0) circle (0.1);}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame} 
\frametitle{test}
\begin{itemize} 
\item Align this properly
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A zoomed-in image:

[image]

## What was the problem with the original code?

A TikZ `\node` has a non-zero `inner sep` and a non-zero `outer sep` whcih were adding additional spacing; you could have suppressed those by using

```
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}{\tikz\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] {\tikz\draw[black,fill=gray] (0,0) circle (0.1);};}
```

but, as I mentioned before, the best approach is simply not to nest the `tikzpicture`s.